# systemd cannot restart service file

Tags: bash, cron, service, systemd, start-stop-daemon

I have written a bash script which I want to run every 60s
(don't worry, I have tried the Script out, it runs perfectly).

Now I wanted to implement it in **systemd** `.service` file, but so far it doesn't restart. The script is beeing executed **one** time and ends with returncode 0 and then the service stops (for ever). So, it just runs ones, but then it ends.

**It won't restart**. I tried out many different things with `RemainAfterExit`, `StartLimitIntervalSec` or `StartLimitBurst`, but nothing worked.

### Here is my .service-file:

```
[Unit]
Description=ExampleScript

[Service]
User=myuser
Restart=allways
RestartSec=60s
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/myuser/start.sh
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Maybe someone of you guys know about System.d and could help me?
Thank you very much!

---

---

### PS:

### service-status while running the script:

```
* examplescript.service - ExampleScript
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/examplescript.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-06-29 23:58:04 CEST; 1s ago
 Main PID: 31860 (bash)
   Memory: 15.6M
   CGroup: /system.slice/examplescript.service
           |-31860 /bin/bash /home/myuser/start.sh
           |-31862 /bin/bash /home/myuser/script/subscript.sh
           `-31871 python /home/myuser/script/subscript.py

Jun 29 23:58:04 mysystem systemd[1]: Started ExampleScript.
```

### service-status after script is finish with rc0:

```
* examplescript.service - ExampleScript
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/examplescript.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2018-06-29 23:58:48 CEST; 2min 42s ago
  Process: 31860 ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/myuser/start.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 31860 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 29 23:58:04 mysystem  systemd[1]: Started ExampleScript.
```

*...systemd is so freaking complicated, cron-job was so much easier*

Comment: You do not have to install units system wide in /usr. There can be user units, `~/.local/share/systemd/user/` for "packages"  or `~/.config/systemd/user/`  for your personal units or overrides.

Answer (score 3):

```
[Service]
User=myuser
Restart=allways   # << fix that
RestartSec=60s
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/myuser/start.sh
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
```

You've misspelled "always" on "Restart=".

Comment: Ohh, no!!!! Why didn't I see that?! ........ such a stupid mistake.....
THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!!!